# Send data to Firebase anonymously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like anonymous users to be able to send data to Firebase but not to delete or overwrite it.

This is what I have been using lately:

My database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

My javascript snippet:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "asdasd",
    databaseURL: "asdasd.firebaseio.com/"
});

var id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
var userData = 'hello';
var sendData = firebase.database().ref("data/" + id + "/").update({userData});

sendData.then(function() { console.log("data sent!") })
```

The obvious problem is that I am exposing my apiKey in the script and anyone could overwrite or delete the data. Is there any practical solution?

Comment: You cannot change the existing data in firebase you can add new anonymous data to firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only allow users to write new data and not change existing data, you can do this in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": "!data.exists()"
  }
}
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on existing vs new data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).

I'd recommend using Firebase's built-in `push()` method for generating the keys, since that adds some predictability to your randomizer without sacrificing the key's unguessability:

```
firebase.database().ref("data")
  .push({userData})
  .then(function() { console.log("data sent!") });
```

Comment: I tried to update the rules, however when I try to publish it this error comes up: Error saving rules – Line 4: ! only operates on booleans.

Comment: Woops, I forgot parenthesis. Added them in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should do like this

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("announcement");
                AbsAnnouncementmodel absAnnouncementmodel=new AbsAnnouncementmodel(receiver,announcement);
                reference.push().setValue(absAnnouncementmodel);
```

here reference related with DatabaseRefence

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!